# Changing part of a list of unequal arrays

Tags: list-manipulation, variable-definitions

I have {x, y, f(x,y)} data in multiple (n x 3) arrays with unequal length, which I read in from different files in order to later plot them using `ListPlot3D`. I wanted to automate the process and save the data into an indexed array. As the length is unequal, a standard 3D would not easily work (I would need to cut the zeros all the time for the plots).

I considered using variable names created by `Symbol["x" <> ToString@i]`, but dealing with this is quite circumstantial.

I saw that people use indexed variables, so that is what I ended up with:

```
Do[x[k]=ReadList["data_"<>k<>".txt", {Number, Number, Number}], {k, 1, ndata}]
```

However, I learned that only symbols allow part assignments, so I e.g., cannot flip the sign using `x[1][[All, 3]] *= -1`. I could copy `x[1]` to an symbol, do the change there, and copy back, but that becomes circumstantial, again.

Is there a way around this?

Any thoughts how to better handle a list of unequal arrays is also appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of assigning individual subsets of data to variables, assign the whole collection to one variable. You could do this with `Table` or several other strategies. Then `x[[1,All,3]]*=-1` should work.

Comment: Thanks! I was familiar with this route, but picked the I indexed variables because when I plot the x[[1]] using listplot3D, I have to delete all the zeros. But maybe that is less problematic.

Comment: There shouldn't be any zeros. Using `Table` won't automatically pad with zeros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution that is quite close to your approach, is to use an `Association` instead of an indexed variable:

```
x = <||>;
Do[x[k]=ReadList["data_"<>k<>".txt", {Number, Number, Number}], {k, 1, ndata}]
```

Now you can do:

```
x[[Key[1], All, 3]] *= -1
```

If you use string keys, you can also get rid of the `Key` wrapper on the lhs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how you can store rows of different length in an anrray using e.g. Table:

```
d = Table[{a[i, j, 1], a[i, j, 1], a[i, j, 3]}, {i, 4}, {j, 
   RandomInteger[{2, 5}]}];
d // TableForm
```

[image]